# Why can't I open my app on Play Store?

Tags: java, android-studio, google-play

I have a basic random number generator app that I created using Android Studio. When I run my app using my test device (plugging my phone in) the app runs perfectly fine. I then uploaded this app to the Google Play Store to show my friends and family. When you download the application it says the app was successfully downloaded, but the app wasn't showing up at all.

In trying to open the app I looked on the Google Play Store and instead of seeing the play app button and uninstall button, it only showed the uninstall button.

[Image of Play Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNvdU.png)

What is wrong with my app that I made? 
What file would do this and how could I fix this? (I can post files if needed)

This my first app that I have made and first stack**overflow** post. Please give me feedback on how I can solve my problem and how I can better ask for help on this platform. Thanks for your time,

PiNet.

Comment: Well does your app have an icon on your Android phone, and, if so, what happens when you try to open it?

Comment: Usually when testing the app it created an icon and worked. But now, it just runs the app as normal. However the icon doesn't show up. I see the problem is most likely to do with this. But what files would fix this?

Comment: That is when I use my phone as test device. No Icon appears either upon downloading from the Play Store.  I though people generally took a while to respond. Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you everybody for helping me solve my issue! Figuring out that playing the app on Android Studio didn't work properly really narrowed down the results from my search and I eventually landed on another stack**overflow** post on the same issue.

I currently can't find the post so I will just give you the answer that I found.

In the androidManifest.xml, in my activity. I had all the actions and categories under the same intent filter. After separating them into two intent filters, my issue was solved!

```
<activity android:name="com.example.random.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>//I only had this intent filter before with the actions & categories above in it

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="android-app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Once again, thank you for your help and your time,

PiNet

Comment: I had same problem and fixed through this post. Thanks!